# extract all the information from nested dictionary on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am learning the nested dictionary on Python. I want to know how I can extract specific information from the nested dictionary. 
My data is the following:

```py
data = {
    "1": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '315'},
    "2": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '120'},
    "3": {'area': None, 'expenditure': '314'},
    "4": {'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': None},
    "5": {'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': '12'},
    "6": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '110'},
    "7": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '300'},
}
```

How can I extract all the information on expenditure in each area? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `[el['expenditure'] for el in data.values()]` will give you a list of the expenditures.

Comment: I know but how can i extract all expenditure information in the specific area? for example, I want to extract all expenditure in administration and all expenditurein aids and appliances

Comment: where are `aids` and `appliances` ?

Comment: It's really helpful in questions like this to show the desired output. What does it mean to `extract all the information`. Is that a dictionary of lists?

Comment: "4":{'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': None}  
"5":{'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': '12'}

Comment: I want to store expenditure in each area separately

Comment: you have to set `value` i.e. "Aids and appliances" for `key` equal to `area`...

Comment: if you want to really get those other values, might as well just filter by the original key numbers before getting into the nested dictionary

Comment: how can I filter the original key numbers?

Comment: to get value, like this: `print(data['1']['expenditure'])`

Answer (score 0):

To find values for key of `expenditure`:

```
for findvals in data.values():
   for k, v in findvals.items():
      if k == "expenditure":
         print(v)

### this prints all the values for key equal to "expenditure"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict`. Create a dictionary with area as keys and expenditure as values in a list.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = {
"1": {'area': 'Administration',  'expenditure': '315'},
"2": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '120'},
"3": {'area': None, 'expenditure':'314'},
"4":{'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': None} ,
"5":{'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': '12'},
"6":{'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '110'},
"7":{'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '300'}
}

storage = defaultdict(list)

# defaultdict allows to define keys on fly
{storage[d['area']].append(d['expenditure']) for _, d in data.items() if d['area']}

# we have append all expenditure to all areas where the area is not None.

print(storage)

# to go back to normal dictionary with list of expenditures 
results = dict(storage)

print(results) 
# outcome: {'Administration': ['315', '120', '110', '300'], 'Aids and appliances': [None, '12']}
```

If you are not familiar with list comprehension, you can use normal for-loop:

```py
# we can re-write this:
{storage[d['area']].append(d['expenditure']) for _, d in data.items() if d['area']}

# to
for _, d in data.items():
    if d['area']:
        storage[d['area']].append(d['expenditure'])
# get all items, and add them to storage if area is not False.
```

I prefer the first for efficiency but you can take second for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[val['expenditure'] for val in data.values() if val['area'] in ['Administration', 'Aids and appliances']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your dictionary all wrong (no comments and typos !)

```
data = 
{'1': {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '315'},
 '2': {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '120'},
 '3': {'area': None, 'expenditure': '314'},
 '4': {'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': None},
 '5': {'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': '12'}}
```

Just do something like this:

```
[[(v.get("area", None),y) for x,y in v.items() if x=='expenditure'] for k,v in data.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a specific `expenditure` on `specific areas`. if you want all areas then just remove a condition from my code or else you can refer all other answers.
I do this as per user input any area name and he'll get `expenditures` of that particular `area`.

```py
    def findExpense(data):
        a = input("Enter area to find expenditure : ")
        ex_dict = {}
        # create expenditure list as values to ex_dict
        ex_dict[a] = []
        for _,vals in data.items():
            if vals['area'] == a:
                ex_dict[a].append(vals['expenditure'])
        return ex_dict

    print(findExpense({
        "1": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '315'},
        "2": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '120'},
        "3": {'area': None, 'expenditure': '314'},
        "4": {'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': None},
        "5": {'area': 'Aids and appliances', 'expenditure': '12'},
        "6": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '110'},
        "7": {'area': 'Administration', 'expenditure': '300'}
    }))
```

If you are familiar with `list comprehension` then you can replace `for` loop with the below code.

```py
    ex_dict[a] = [vals['expenditure'] for _, vals in data.items() if vals['area'] == a]
    return ex_dict
```

Comment: You could also use .values() instead of .items() :)

Comment: In my code, if I use `values()` instead of `items()` It will give`TypeError` at condition @Cedric. so we have to modify code if we use `values()`.

Comment: Right I think you would need a cast. Forgot about that

Comment: Yes definitely, cause of nested dictionary.